# awk not rounding with OFMT and $0

Tags: awk, gawk

I'm printing an array with 100 columns and I would like all columns to have 2 decimals. I would like to use print $0 and not have to individually specify the format for all columns.

OFMT does seen to work with $0:

```
echo '0.77767686 0.76555555 0.6667667 0.77878878' |awk '{CONVFMT="%.2g";OFMT="%.2g";print ($0+0);print ($0+0)"";print $0}'
```

Results:

```
0.78
0.78
0.77767686 0.76555555 0.6667667 0.77878878
```

Comment: `$0` is a string, not a number! Use `$1`..`$4`.

Answer (score 10):

Note that all input is treated as strings until implicitly converted by how it is used.

`OFMT` is used when <strike>strings are converted to numbers</strike> numbers are printed, e.g.:

```
<<< 0.77767686 awk '{ print 0+$0 }' OFMT='%.2g'
```

`CONVFMT` is used when numbers are explicitly converted to strings, e.g.:

```
<<< 0.77767686 awk '{ print "" 0+$0 }' CONVFMT='%.2g'
```

Output in both cases:

```
0.78
```

The latter converts `$0` into a number and then concatenates it with the empty string.

To achieve this for every column I would suggest using a sensible setting of the input and output record separators:

```
<<< '0.77767686 0.76555555 0.6667667 0.77878878' \
awk '{ print 0+$0 RT }' CONVFMT='%.2g' RS='[ \t\n]+' ORS=''
```

Note the two conversions, first to a number with `0+$0` then back to a string by concatenating it with `RT`. `RT` will be set to the matched record separator. Note that this is GNU awk specific, for a more portable solution, use a loop, e.g.:

```
<<< '0.77767686 0.76555555 0.6667667 0.77878878' \
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i+=0 } 1' CONVFMT='%.2g'
```

Output in both cases:

```
0.78 0.77 0.67 0.78
```

#### Edit - Responding to @BeeOnRope

@BeeOnRope is correct, `OFMT` is used as the format specifier when the print-function calls `sprintf()`, while `CONVFMT` is used in other conversions. Here is an example that illustrates the difference:

```
<<< 0.77767686 awk '{ n=0+$1; s=""n; print n, s }' OFMT='%.2g' CONVFMT='%.3g'
```

Output:

```
0.78 0.778
```

Two relevant sections from the GNU awk manual:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/OFMT.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html

Comment: That's not correct. Both OMFT and CONVFMT are used for number to string conversions. The difference is that OFMT is used specifically when such a conversion is performed inside a call to print (i.e., print receives a number and needs to format it for output). CONVFMT is used for other conversions that naturally arise e.g. when a string is concatenated to a number and so on.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Thanks I learnt something then.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use a `for` loop?

```
echo '0.77767686 0.76555555 0.6667667 0.77878878' |awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%.2f\n", $i }'
```

Results:

```
0.78
0.77
0.67
0.78
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned you need to treat the field as a number to get a conversion.  To combine some other ideas you can try:

```
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) $i += 0; print }'
```

That will convert *every* field to a number.  You can just convert individual fields with `$7 += 0` and so on.  You could get fancier by using `if (match($i, ...))` with some regexp to select only the numbers you want to convert.