# bash awk round number

Tags: bash, awk

I want to spit out RAM usage as a percentage of total RAM using `top`.  The script I have so far is

```
top -l 1 |
awk '/PhysMem/ {
    print "RAM\nwired:" $2/40.95 "% active:" $4/40.95 "% inactive:" $6/40.95 "% free:" $10/40.95 "%"
}'
```

I have 4gb RAM, hence divide by 40.95, so this script spits out something that looks like:

```
RAM
wired:16.1172% active:46.2759% inactive:8.79121% free:28.8156%
```

I only want it to show the percentages to 1 place past the decimal and I'm not sure how to do this.  I looked into using `bc` but I always get an illegal statement error. Any ideas how to round it to the 1st decimal place within awk?

Comment: why not use `free` instead? it's much more amenable to parsing/manipulation than top's output is.

Comment: im running osx so there is no `free` command. have to work with `top`

Comment: You may find this of interest http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4286/is-there-a-mac-os-x-terminal-version-of-the-free-command-in-linux-systems

Comment: @flapjacks Aside: I needed some very like alias for me (`top` was slightly too slow). Check out `vm_stat | awk -F: 'BEGIN{OFMT="%.f"}; /(free|wired|active)/ {print substr($1, 7),"\r\t\t",($2*4096)/2^20}'`

Answer (score 5):

There are a few ways to do that with awk:

```
... | awk '{ print $2/40.95 }' OFMT="%3.1f"

... | awk '{ printf( "%3.1f\n", $2/40.95 )}'
```

each use the output format `%3.1f` to handle rounding.  So all you need to do is add the argument `OFMT="%3.1f"` to your awk call.  (Or you may prefer a format of `%0.1f`  The 3 just gives a minimum width; the typical format string rules apply. )

Comment: Note that depending on your particular case you may need `CONVFMT` instead of `OFMT` — more details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12889541/812102).