# setting default numeric format in awk

Tags: awk, formatting

I wanted to do a simple parsing of two files with ids and some corresponding numerical values. I didn't want awk to print numbers in scientific notation.

File looks like this:

```
someid-1 860025 50.0401 4.00022
someid-2 384319 22.3614 1.78758
someid-3 52096 3.03118 0.242314
someid-4 43770 2.54674 0.203587
someid-5 33747 1.96355 0.156967
someid-6 20281 1.18004 0.0943328
someid-7 12231 0.711655 0.0568899
someid-8 10936 0.636306 0.0508665
someid-9 10224.8 0.594925 0.0475585
someid-10 10188.8 0.59283 0.047391
```

when use print instead of printf :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{x[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in x){split(x[$1],k,FS); print $1,k[2],k[3],k[4],$2,$3,$4}' OSCAo.txt dme_miRNA_PIWI_OSC.txt | sort -n -r -k 7 | head
```

i get this result:

```
dme-miR-iab-4-5p      0.333333    0.000016    0.000001  0.25    0.000605606 9.36543e-07
dme-miR-9c-5p   10987.300000      0.525413    0.048798  160.2   0.388072    0.000600137
dme-miR-9c-3p   731.986000    0.035003    0.003251  2.10714 0.00510439  7.89372e-06
dme-miR-9b-5p   30322.500000      1.450020    0.134670  595.067 1.4415  0.00222922
dme-miR-9b-3p   2628.280000   0.125684    0.011673  48  0.116276    0.000179816
dme-miR-9a-3p    10.365000    0.000496    0.000046  0.25    0.000605606 9.36543e-07
dme-miR-999-5p  103.433000    0.004946    0.000459  0.0769231   0.00018634  2.88167e-07
dme-miR-999-3p  1513.790000   0.072389    0.006723  28  0.0678278   0.000104893
dme-miR-998-5p  514.000000    0.024579    0.002283  73  0.176837    0.000273471
dme-miR-998-3p  3529.000000   0.168756    0.015673  42  0.101742    0.000157339
```

*Notice the scientific notation in the last column*

I understand that printf with appropriate format modifier can do the job but the code becomes very lengthy. I have to write something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{x[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in x){split(x[$1],k,FS); printf "%s\t%3.6f\t%3.6f\t%3.6f\t%3.6f\t%3.6f\t%3.6f\n", $1,k[2],k[3],k[4],$2,$3,$4}' file1.txt file2.txt > fileout.txt
```

This becomes clumsy when I have to parse `fileout` with another similarly structured file.

Is there any way to specify default **numerical** output, such that any string will be printed like a string but all numbers follow a particular format.

Comment: will it work the way u want if u use %9s itself instead of %3.6f  ?

Comment: `OFMT` is used when strings are converted into numbers and `CONVFMT` is used when doing the opposite, see my discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12889541/1331399) for a bit more detail. I'm not sure how to convert your example to use this because it is not clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Thor. thanks.. corrected the question.. i wanted to know if there is any way of assigning a default numerical output format in the `BEGIN` module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think You misinterpreted the meaning of `%3.6f`. The first number before the decimal point is the field width not the "number of digits before decimal point". (See [prinft(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf))

So You should use `%10.6f` instead. It can be tested easily in `bash`

```
$ printf "%3.6f\n%3.6f\n%3.6f" 123.456 12.345 1.234
123.456000
12.345000
1.234000
$ printf "%10.6f\n%10.6f\n%10.6f" 123.456 12.345 1.234
123.456000
 12.345000
  1.234000
```

You can see that the later aligns to the decimal point properly.

As `sidharth c nadhan` mentioned You can use the `OFMT` `awk` internal variable (seem [awk(1)](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/awk/)). An example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{print 123.456; print 12.345; print 1.234}'
123.456
12.345
1.234
$ awk -vOFMT=%10.6f 'BEGIN{print 123.456; print 12.345; print 1.234}'
123.456000
 12.345000
  1.234000
```

As I see in You example the number with maximum digits can be 123456.1234567, so the format `%15.7f` to cover all and show a nice looking table.

But unfortunately it will not work if the number has no decimal point in it or even if it does, but it ends with `.0`.

```
$ awk -vOFMT=%15.7f 'BEGIN{print 123.456;print 123;print 123.0;print 0.0+123.0}'
    123.4560000
123
123
123
```

I even tried `gawk`'s `strtonum()` function, but the integers are considered as non-OFMT strings. See

```
awk -vOFMT=%15.7f -vCONVFMT=%15.7f 'BEGIN{print 123.456; print strtonum(123); print strtonum(123.0)}'
```

It has the same output as before.

So I think, you have to use `printf` anyway. The script can be a little bit shorter and a bit more configurable:

```
awk -vf='\t'%15.7f 'NR==FNR{x[$1]=sprintf("%s"f f f,$1,$2,$3,$4);next}$1 in x{printf("%s"f f f"\n",x[$1],$2,$3,$4)}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

The script will not work properly if there are duplicated IDs in the first file. If it does not happen then the two conditions can be changed and the `;next` can be left off.

Comment: thanks.. but it still doesnt solve the problem of the scientific notation. for e.g. 5-e06 should be printed as 0.0000005

Comment: @bharat_iyengar: Yes, it does. See `echo 5e-6|awk '{printf("%14.6f",$1)}'` prints `"      0.000005"`. It is expected, isn't it?

Comment: yes it does.. but if you have multiple numerical fields to be printed and you dont want to write `%10.6f` for each of them: is it possible ?

Comment: @bharat_iyengar: I checked the "normal" `OFMT` and `CONVFMT` as well, but it does not solve the problem that a string containing only numbers is considered as integer not a float, so those defined formats are not used (see [gawk(3) conversion](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conversion.html)). But this also applied numbers like `123.0`. So to print an integer as float you have to use `printf`. In the presented solution you have to specify the output format only once. Is it not a proper solution for your problem?

Comment: @bharat_iyengar: As I showed, you can set the format for `float` numbers, but it will not work for `integers` (123.0 considered as an integer by awk). So if You mix them, You need to use `printf`.  But You can reduce the number of format string usage. See my examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{x[$1]=$0;next} ($1 in x){split(x[$1],k,FS); printf "%s\t%9s\t%9s\t%9s\t%9s\t%9s\t%9s\n", $1,k[2],k[3],k[4],$2,$3,$4}' file1.txt file2.txt > fileout.txt
```