# Reading variable with double float precision from a text file with gnuplot

Tags: awk, gnuplot

I have a text file, containing data in 3 columns like below:

```
0.0100000000 0.0058077299 -0.0000000288
0.0110000000 0.0075128707 -0.0000000373
0.0120000000 0.0093579693 -0.0000000465
```

I want to get the variables from this file in gnuplot and use them to draw graphs:

What I exactly do is like below (e.g: to pick the variable from row 2 column 3):

```
ii  = 2
a_0 = system("awk '{ if (NR == " . ii . ") printf \"%f\", $3}' " .datafile)
a_0 = a_0+0.
```

but what is written as a_0 is zero!

How can I increase the precision to get the exact value?

Comment: How are you printing `a_0`? It may help to use a formatted print command like `sprintf` or `gprintf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is with the explicit way awk is instructed to read the number. When the precision is left out of the format specifier `%.6f` is assumed, thus awk returns `0.000000` for the number in the 3rd column on the 2nd line. You can fix this in a number of ways:

1. Use a higher precision format specifier:

   `a_0 = system("awk 'NR == ".ii." { printf \"%.10f\", $3 }' ".datafile)`

   <sub><sup>Note that there is implicitly a boolean expression at the head of each code-block in awk, so the if-statement is redundant here.</sup></sub>
2. Avoid numerical conversion in awk entirely:

   `a_0 = system("awk 'NR == ".ii." { print $3 }' ".datafile)`
3. Use higher precision conversion by setting `OFMT`:

   `a_0 = system("awk 'NR == ".ii." { print 0+$3 }' OFMT='%.10f' ".datafile)`

   Further discussion about numerical conversion in awk can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12889541/1331399) I gave concerning a similar issue.

The result of running `print a_0` at the end of the script is in all cases:

```
-3.73e-08
```

Comment: Perfect, I tried the first solution and it works.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A rather late answer, but there was and is no need to involve `awk`, you can do it easily with gnuplot. gnuplot will return the value as floating point number in a reasonable format.

**Data:** `SO24041433.dat`

```
0.0100000000 0.0058077299 -0.0000000288
0.0110000000 0.0075128707 -0.0000000373
0.0120000000 0.0093579693 -0.0000000465
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot 4.6.0, March 2012)

```
### extract specific value
reset

FILE = "SO24041433.dat"

myRow = 2
myCol = 3

stats FILE u (myValue=column(myCol)) every ::myRow-1::myRow-1 nooutput

print myValue
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
-3.73e-008
```